# Black background in Mac AppStore icon

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I just published my first Mac App Store application, and I realized my application icon has a black rounded border around it.

This border never appears outside of the App Store (such as on Xcode or in Launchpad).

[image: App Store screenshot]

App Store link: https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/display-power-manager/id903133507?l=en&mt=12

Did anyone else have the same experience? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue. I have opened a thread on Apple developer forum, you can track it here: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/238543

Comment: This is a general problem affecting numerous developers, see the thread above. Looks like Apple introduced a bug recently and should fix it!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen a couple of times, and I seem to recall that it was due to PNG compression.

Create a new version and make sure your icon is exported as a 24-bit PNG without any compression or interlacing. I never had any issues by using the *Export for web* feature of Photoshop.

Comment: Hum... unfortunately I am already using 24-bit non-interlaced PNG. Thanks for your response.